# When using boto is it safe to have a long running client object?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

So let's say I have a long running web server that makes calls to the aws api? Is it safe to have a long running client object, or will that object possibly get corrupted and mess up my web server? For concreteness is it better to do something like this

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('elb')

def function():
    do stuff with client
```

or this

```
import boto3

def function():
    client = boto3.client('elb')
    do stuff with client
```

The former option is better because I can reuse the same client object in multiple function. The latter option would be better if my above safety concern is valid.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34929985, https://stackoverflow.com/q/53790668, https://stackoverflow.com/q/52820971, https://stackoverflow.com/q/59737296

Comment: not sure about "safe", but examples from [aws-developer-workshop](https://github.com/amazon-archives/aws-developer-workshop/blob/9b0e912998b586cd5524c9c858e305473dc023c7/episode2/scripts/compareFaces.py#L13), [boto3-sample](https://github.com/boto/boto3-sample/blob/5a5b0e38074c65c84a7e3f4a259ece8f3f9dd136/transcoder.py#L156), and many more from [aws-samples](https://github.com/aws-samples), all use something similar to the first approach

Answer (score 0):

My preferred method of doing something like this is passing the client as a parameter to the function that will use it. Something like

```
import boto3

def function(param1, param2, client=None):
    if client is None:
        client = boto3.client('elb') # use default client

    return client.do_stuff(param1, param2)

def function2(param3, param4, client=None):
    if client is None:
        client = boto3.client('elb') # use default client

    return client.do_different_stuff(param3, param4)
```

Then you can call it like:

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('elb')
stuff = function("a", "b", client=client)
different_stuff = function2("c", "d", client=client)
```

This is an improvement over instantiating it inside the function because you can use a single client for multiple operations, but you don't have to ensure that the client exists in a readable scope for all of those functions - you just pass it as a parameter.

Comment: What's the benefit of doing that over putting it in the closure?

Comment: You can create a single client and have it perform multiple different actions with different functions. I've added a little to my answer - hopefully that explains it.

Comment: this doesn't answer the question