# Should I create a new instance of boto3 client for each file upload request, or use a shared instance

Tags: python, flask, boto3

I was wondering, should I create a new instance of boto3 client for each file upload request, or use a shared instance? Which is the correct way to do so?

### Create a new instance each upload request

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def upload_file():
    file = request.files['file']

    file.save('/tmp/file.ext')

    client = boto3.client('s3')

    client.upload_file('/tmp/file.ext',  # Path to local file
        'my-space',  # Name of Space
        'file.ext')  # Name for remote file
```

---

### Shared instance for each upload request

```
client = boto3.client('s3')

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def upload_file():
    file = request.files['file']

    file.save('/tmp/file.ext')

    client.upload_file('/tmp/file.ext',  # Path to local file
        'my-space',  # Name of Space
        'file.ext')  # Name for remote file
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52820971/is-boto3-client-thread-safe

Answer (score 0):

I would opt for the shared client.

```
client = boto3.client('s3')

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def upload_file():
    file = request.files['file']

    file.save('/tmp/file.ext')

    client.upload_file('/tmp/file.ext', 'my-space', 'file.ext')
```

Comment: But, is it safe, to share a single `boto3` instance across multiple requests?